# How to implement multiple filter criteria in Vaadin Grid?

Tags: vaadin

When I want to apply a simple filter on one field, I can just put the name of that field in the `path` attribute:

```
<vaadin-grid-filter path="field that we wanna filter">
```

What is the syntax if I want to filter on multiple fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using V10+ perhaps this can help:
https://www.flowingcode.com/en/lazy-filtered-and-sorted-vaadin-grid-using-external-data-source/

For V8 there's an answer here:
https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17591983/how-to-apply-multiple-filters-to-vaadin-8-grid